# How to calculate overlaping time and length of conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Employee table has four columns. Employee, Start, End, Diff. Diff column is the duration and calculated as End - Start.

I want to find the conflict between the Start and End time range. 
For instance, Employee A has three rows: 
First rows Start time is 01:02 and end time is 01:05 but second row start time is 01:03 which is a conflict in the first row data.

### Sample Data:

```
   employee   StartDate    EndDate       Start         End        Diff 
    A       04/08/2019   04/08/2019       01:02:00   01:05:00       3
    A       04/08/2019   04/08/2019       01:03:00   01:08:00       5
    A       04/08/2019   04/08/2019       01:014:00  01:21:00       7
    B       04/08/2019   04/08/2019       02:00:00   02:17:00      17
```

I want to only select the specific start and end time for employee A that has an overlap in their start and end time and want to calculate total length of conflict in a new column using t-sql. i'm a newbie and need help. please anyone?

```
SELECT TOP (100) a.ccx_employeename AS employee
    ,CONVERT(Date,[a].[ccx_starttime]) AS [Start Date],CONVERT(Date,[a].[ccx_endtime]) AS [End Date], CONVERT(time (0), a.ccx_starttime) AS StartTime
    , CONVERT(time (0), a.ccx_endtime) AS EndTime
    , CONVERT (time(0), (a.ccx_endtime - a.ccx_starttime)) AS Duration
FROM ccp_sim_MSCRM.dbo.Filteredccx_Recorded_Service as a 
where CONVERT(time (0), a.ccx_starttime) BETWEEN CONVERT(time (0), a.ccx_starttime) And CONVERT(time (0), a.ccx_endtime)
```

As first and second rows has conflict I want to show that two rows. As well as conflict duration is 2 minutes in this example. First row end time is 01:05 but second rows start time is 01:03 so conflict duration is 01:05 - 01:03 = 2 minutes

**Desired Output**

```
employee   StartDate    EndDate       Start         End        Diff 
A       04/08/2019   04/08/2019       01:02:00   01:05:00       3
A       04/08/2019   04/08/2019       01:03:00   01:08:00       5

duration of conflict : 2 mins
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Sybase or MS SQL Server?

Comment: MS Sql server management studio

Comment: So to better understand your issue, and to try and spark some ideas of your own... You basically want a result set of any row for employees who have an end time greater than the start time of the row beneath. You will need to group on the employee as well as order by start time. Something else to consider are dates, I don't see any indication of it here but that may need to be considered because your logic needs to understand that the time on one day doesn't care about the times of other days.. Finally, no need for `TOP 100` that may just limit you down the road.

Comment: haag1 the date for the start and end time is same. for example for employee A both the time ranges are for same date as in  04/08/2019 start and  time for one job is 01:02:00- 01:05:00 and for the second job 01:03:00-01:08:00 what would be the modification in that case?

Comment: Very nice job presenting your question, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would join the table over itself, though maybe not the most effective :

```
SELECT
    e1.employee,
    e1.Start as firstStart,
    e1.End as firstEnd,
    e2.Start as secondStart,
    e2.End as secondEnd,
    e1.End - e2.Start as conflictDuration
FROM
    Employee as e1 inner join
    Employee as e2 on (
        e1.employee = e2.employee and 
        e2.Start < e1.End and
        e2.End > e1.Start
    )
```

Comment: I've made some changes in the question if you wanna take a look again. Thanks

Comment: might be better now, I forgot a condition in my join clause

Comment: This logic doesn't really gives the desired output as I was trying to pick only the records that has conflict . this one tries to take every record and break it into a conflict !

Comment: And only returns pairs of records (as a new record) that contains a conflict. The inner join and the on clause make sur of that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few parts to your question:

- finding the conflicting rows
- calculating the conflicting time
- output in your desired format

The solution below only covers the first two parts and assumes a combined date and time field.

I have added some unique key to deduplicate the results and "sort" the rows for comparison. In the code below, it is "id".

```
declare @t table (id int identity,employee char(1), StartDateTime smalldatetime, EndDateTime smalldatetime, diff as DATEDIFF(minute,StartDateTime,EndDateTime))
insert into @t values('A','2019-04-08 01:02','2019-04-08 01:05')
insert into @t values('A','2019-04-08 01:03','2019-04-08 01:08')
insert into @t values('A','2019-04-08 01:14','2019-04-08 01:21')
insert into @t values('B','2019-04-08 02:00','2019-04-08 02:17')

SELECT T1.employee, T1.StartDateTime, T1.EndDateTime, T2.StartDateTime, T2.EndDateTime
,      (T1.diff + T2.diff)
       - DATEDIFF(minute, CASE WHEN T1.StartDateTime < T2.StartDateTime THEN T1.StartDateTime ELSE T2.StartDateTime END   -- MIN(Start)
                        , CASE WHEN T1.EndDateTime   > T2.EndDateTime   THEN T1.EndDateTime   ELSE T2.EndDateTime   END)  -- MAX(End)
       AS "duration of conflict"
FROM @t AS T1
JOIN @t AS T2
  ON  T2.employee = T1.employee
  AND T2.id       > T1.id        -- Each only once
  AND T2.StartDateTime < T1.EndDateTime
  AND T2.EndDateTime   > T1.StartDateTime
```

Comment: any other way without using table variables?

Comment: coz you're creating table variable for this small portion of data set but if it's thousands of records then it's not really efficient by doing this way...or I'm wrong?

Comment: The use of the table variable is not important. You can use a regular table instead. If you had provided the statements to create test data, I would have used yours.

When it somes to performance, a query like this needs an index on the columns that you are joining them on. In the example query I posted, an index on (employee, id) would be ideal.

Having said that, to get the result you ask for, you have to join the table with itself, there is no other way (or more correctly: there is no better performing way).

Answer (score 0):

This feels like the perfect place to use the `LEAD`/`LAG` functions to me. Combine that with some sub queries and `IIF` statements and you can calculate the results you're looking for.

Example:

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE
(
    Employee VARCHAR(1),
    startDate DATE,
    endDate DATE,
    [start] TIME,
    [end] TIME,
    diff AS DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[start],[end])
)

INSERT INTO @Employee (Employee, startDate, endDate, start, [end])
VALUES
    ('A',CAST('2019-04-08' AS DATE),CAST('2019-04-08' AS DATE),'01:02:00','01:05:00'),
    ('A',CAST('2019-04-08' AS DATE),CAST('2019-04-08' AS DATE),'01:03:00','01:08:00'),
    ('A',CAST('2019-04-08' AS DATE),CAST('2019-04-08' AS DATE),'01:14:00','01:21:00'),
    ('B',CAST('2019-04-08' AS DATE),CAST('2019-04-08' AS DATE),'02:00:00','02:17:00')

SELECT
    Employee.Employee,
    Employee.startDate,
    Employee.endDate,
    Employee.start,
    Employee.[end],
    diff,
    (IIF(ISNULL(lagConflict,0)>0,ISNULL(lagConflict,0),0)+IIF(ISNULL(Employee.leadConflict,0)>0,ISNULL(Employee.leadConflict,0),0)) AS conflict
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Employee,
            startDate,
            endDate,
            start,
            [end],
            diff,
            DATEDIFF
            (
                MINUTE,
                [start],
                LAG([end],1)
                OVER
                (
                    PARTITION BY
                        Employee,
                        startDate,
                        endDate
                    ORDER BY
                        [start],
                        [end]
                )
            ) AS lagConflict,
            DATEDIFF
            (
                MINUTE,
                [end],
                LEAD([start],1)
                OVER
                (
                    PARTITION BY
                        Employee,
                        startDate,
                        endDate
                    ORDER BY
                        [start],
                        [end]
                )
            )*-1 AS leadConflict
        FROM
            @Employee
    ) AS Employee
WHERE
    Employee.leadConflict > 0
    OR Employee.lagConflict > 0;
```

Microsoft SQL Docs: LAG][1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Dean , is there anyway we can avoid the table variables in the beginning ? I feel like for a high volume table with thousands of records the table variable wouldn't be a good idea...correct me if I'm wrong or if you have a suggestion for me so that I can implement this query for a high volume table with thousands of records.

Comment: The table variable is just for the example. In your environment I'm assuming your `Employee` table would be a standard table/tables with proper indexes.